# Visiting Paris while in Transit to Portugal

Tags: schengen

I am an Indian Citizen having Schengen Visa (single entry) issued by Portugal Embassy for travelling to Lisbon for business. I have a 10 hr transit in Paris. Can I leave the airport to visit Paris during this layover time ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- since France and Portugal are both in the Schengen zone, you will clear Schengen immigration as soon as you land in Paris *anyway*. There will be no further immigration checks either boarding or disembarking form the Paris-Lisbon flight (though the airline may want to see ID at boarding to make sure you're the person they sold a ticket to), and you can freely go to into Paris while you're waiting.

Just make sure to allow enough time for the *security* check when you get back to the airport to board your Lisbon flight.

Comment: And be careful with traveling time to Paris airport. Additionally double check there are not any strike the day you are doing this day out in Paris.There often are strikes on the public transports in Paris & they can easily make you miss your flight